# Generating all permutation of numbers that sums up to N

Tags: java, recursion, combinations, permutation

I am writing a program to create a recursive permutation of all numbers<=N that add up to a given number N. However I am at a loss on how to create that permutation. Any insights would be appreciated.

At first I was trying to partition the numbers using the partition function and permutate each number set later, however I don't think it would work and the best way is the recursively permutate while summing the numbers which is way over my head.

Sorry if this sounds really dumb. But I really have no idea.

Example:

```
Input: 4

Output: [[4],[3,1],[1,3],[2,2],[1,1,2],[1,2,1],[2,1,1],[1,1,1,1]]
```

```
public class Perm{


    public List<List<Integer>> partition(int num, int maxNum, List<List<Integer>> arr, ArrayList<Integer> temp){
        if (num == 0) {
            arr.add((List<Integer>)temp.clone());
            temp.clear();
        }
        else{
            for (int i = Math.min(maxNum, num); i >= 1; i--) {
                temp.add(i);
                System.out.println(temp);
                partition(num-i, i, arr, temp);
            }
        }

        return arr;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you're trying to solve?

Example number N and solution

Comment: I updated my post with the example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were very close, but you need to undo `temp.add(i)` before continuing the iteration. That is most easily done using a [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) instead of a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

This is how I would write it:

```java
public static List<List<Integer>> combosWithSum(int sum) {
    if (sum < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Sum cannot be negative: " + sum);
    if (sum == 0)
        return Collections.emptyList();
    List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    buildCombosWithSum(sum, new ArrayDeque<>(), result);
    return result;
}

private static void buildCombosWithSum(int sum, Deque<Integer> combo, List<List<Integer>> result) {
    for (int num = sum; num > 0; num--) {
        combo.addLast(num);
        if (num == sum)
            result.add(new ArrayList<>(combo));
        else
            buildCombosWithSum(sum - num, combo, result);
        combo.removeLast();
    }
}
```

*Test*

```java
combosWithSum(5).forEach(System.out::println);
```

*Output*

```
[5]
[4, 1]
[3, 2]
[3, 1, 1]
[2, 3]
[2, 2, 1]
[2, 1, 2]
[2, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 4]
[1, 3, 1]
[1, 2, 2]
[1, 2, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 3]
[1, 1, 2, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 2]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

To get the result in the order shown in the question, add the following line before `return result;`:

```java
result.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(List::size));
```

```
[5]
[4, 1]
[3, 2]
[2, 3]
[1, 4]
[3, 1, 1]
[2, 2, 1]
[2, 1, 2]
[1, 3, 1]
[1, 2, 2]
[1, 1, 3]
[2, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 2, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 2, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 2]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Nice answer. These are termed integer compositions or ordered partitions. There are 2^(n-1) compositions of an integer n.