# Listing all integer compositions in R

Tags: r, algorithm, partitioning, combinatorics

What I look for is basically an R-version of the answer to this question: [Generating all permutation of numbers that sums up to N](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61853351/generating-all-permutation-of-numbers-that-sums-up-to-n). First of all the answer uses java, which I have a really hard time reading. Second of all the code uses "deque", which I cant figure out a way to implement in R.
I have found several algorithms to do this, but they have all been written in programming languages using structures not available in R such as deques, heaps or list-comprehensions.

What I actually need is a way of finding all the vectors `v` of length N-1 where:
`sum(v * 1:(N-1)) == N`
and I think I can manage that myself if only I find a way of obtaining all the ordered integer partitions.

As an example for N = 4 all the ordered integer partitions using numbers 1 to N-1 are:

```
1+1+1+1

1+1+2

1+3

2+2
```

What I effectively need is output of the either form:

```
c(1,1,1,1)

c(1,1,2)

c(1,3)

c(2,2)
```

Or of the form:

```
c(4,0,0)

c(2,1,0)

c(1,0,1)

c(0,2,0)
```

since I should be able to convert the former format to the latter by myself. Any hint as to how to approach this problem using R would be greatly appreciated. The latter format is excactly the vectors `v` such that `sum(v * 1:3)` is 4.

**EDIT:**
My own attempt:

```
rek = function(mat, id1, id2){
  if(id1 + id2 != length(mat) + 1){ #If next state not absorbing
    mat[id1] = mat[id1] - 1
    mat[id2] = mat[id2] - 1
    mat[id1+id2] = mat[id1+id2] + 1
    out = mat
    
    id = which(mat > 0)
    for(i in id){
      for(j in id[id>=i]){
        if(j == i & mat[i] == 1){
          next
        }
        out = rbind(out, rek(mat,i,j))
      }
    }
    return(out)
  }
}
start = c(n, rep(0, n-2))
states = rbind(start, rek(start, 1, 1))
states = states[!duplicated(states), ] #only unique states.
```

This is incredibly inefficient. E. g. when `n` = 11, my `states` has over 120,000 rows prior to removing duplicates, which leaves only 55 rows.

**EDIT 2:**
Using the `parts()` function described below I came up with:

```
temp = partitions::parts(n)
temp = t(temp)
for(i in 1:length(temp[,1])){
  row = temp[i,]
  if(any(row>(n-1))){#if absorbing state
    next
  }
  counts = plyr::count(row[row>0])
  newrow = rep(0,n-1)
  id = counts$x
  numbs = counts$freq
  newrow[id] = numbs
  states = rbind(states, newrow)
}
states = states[-1,]#removing the first row, added manually
```

which excactly gives me the vectors `v` such that `sum(v * 1:(N-1))` is N.

If anyone is interested, this is to be used within coalescent theory, as a way to describe the possible relations between N individuals omitting when all are related. As an example with N = 4:

(4, 0, 0) -- No individuals are related

(2, 1, 0) -- Two individuals are related, the rest are not

(0, 2, 0) -- The individuals are pair-wise related

(1, 0, 1) -- Three individuals are related, the other individual is not.

Comment: How big is the real problem you need to use this for?

Comment: I hope it is possible to do for a very large N, but I think there is a limit. I have actually come up with a very inefficient method, which "dies" around N = 13. For this I have found the permutations to be: 
N=2: 1, 
N=3: 2, 
N=4: 4, 
N=5: 6, 
N=6: 10, 
N=7: 14, 
N=8: 21, 
N=9: 29, 
N=10: 41, 
N=11: 55, 
N=12: 76, 
however, I am not 100% sure it is correct, since I didn't bother checking if I got everything, because the algorithm was way too slow.

Comment: For more complex data structures I recommended https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/collections/index.html

Comment: @polkas Thank you. This will be very useful also in future functions of mine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope `parts` from package `partitions` could help

```
library(partitions)
N <- 4
res <- unique(lapply(asplit(parts(N),2),function(x) sort(x[x>0])))[-1]
```

which gives

```
> res
[[1]]
[1] 1 3

[[2]]
[1] 2 2

[[3]]
[1] 1 1 2

[[4]]
[1] 1 1 1 1
```

---

If you would like to write a custom ***base R*** function, here is a recursive version

```
f <- function(n, vhead = n, v = c()) {
  if (n == 0) return(list(v))
  unlist(lapply(seq_len(min(n, vhead)), function(k) f(n - k, k, c(k,v))), recursive = FALSE)
}
```

then we can run

```
res <- Filter(function(x) length(x)>1,f(N))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The ```parts()```  is quite useful, both for answering my actual question in the form of your answer, where it is wrapped in other functions. But the format of just wirtiting ```t(parts(N))``` actually makes it very easy to fulfill my underlying need. 
I don't understand how the library didn't appear during my google search prior to asking the question.